# How to setup haproxy for Sonarqube

Tags: jenkins, sonarqube

When we setup haproxy with redirect and reverse proxy from `http://sonar.company.com` to `http://sonar-server.company.com:8080`. Though the URL is opening fine, we are getting below issue while running sonar runner in Jenkins-

```
INFO: ------------------------------------------------------------------------
INFO: EXECUTION FAILURE
INFO: ------------------------------------------------------------------------
Total time: 0.185s
Final Memory: 1M/117M
INFO: ------------------------------------------------------------------------
ERROR: Error during Sonar runner execution
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Fail to download libraries from server
    at org.sonar.runner.impl.Jars.dowloadFiles(Jars.java:78)
    at org.sonar.runner.impl.Jars.download(Jars.java:57)
    at org.sonar.runner.impl.JarDownloader.download(JarDownloader.java:46)
    at org.sonar.runner.impl.JarDownloader.checkVersionAndDownload(JarDownloader.java:37)
    at org.sonar.runner.impl.BatchLauncher$1.run(BatchLauncher.java:71)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at org.sonar.runner.impl.BatchLauncher.doExecute(BatchLauncher.java:69)
    at org.sonar.runner.impl.BatchLauncher.execute(BatchLauncher.java:50)
    at org.sonar.runner.api.EmbeddedRunner.doExecute(EmbeddedRunner.java:102)
    at org.sonar.runner.api.Runner.execute(Runner.java:100)
    at org.sonar.runner.Main.executeTask(Main.java:70)
    at org.sonar.runner.Main.execute(Main.java:59)
    at org.sonar.runner.Main.main(Main.java:53)
Caused by: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 1
    at org.sonar.runner.impl.Jars.dowloadFiles(Jars.java:72)
    ... 12 more
```

Any idea about issue or this is bug with sonarqube?

Answer (score 1):

You should check your proxy set up is not changing response from /batch_bootstrap/index. Please compare response from:
http://sonar.company.com/batch_bootstrap/index and http://sonar-server.company.com:8080/batch_bootstrap/index

++

Comment: Yes we got in working by setting reverse proxy in HAProxy setup.